# Postgres not deleting user on query when given username as a parameter

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm building a database of users using Node.JS. I've successfully created the DB in posgres and hooked up my backend in db.js. I created and populated my users table with some test data, which I am able to query directly from my terminal in postgres

[users table with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSzA6.png)

In my index.js file, I have the following-

```
const pool = require("./db");
app.use(express.json());

app.delete("/users/:user_name", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { user_name } = req.params;
    const deleteUser = await pool.query(
      "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name = $1",
      [user_name],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
          console.log(result);
          res.send("User was Deleted");
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

With the server running on port 5000, I can send a request through postman to -

```
http://localhost:5000/users/:Timmy
```

I get back `"User was Deleted"` in Postman, and I don't receive an error. The result logged in the console is

```
Result {
  command: 'DELETE',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: undefined,
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
      },
      RowCtor: null,
      rowAsArray: false
}
```

Yet when I query the DB in my terminal to test that the query worked, Timmy is still there.

[users table after postman query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPE0b.png)

I'm not sure what the issue is here. I am able to make a deletion in terminal using-

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name = 'Timmy';
```

However I see that I have to use single quotes around the user_name parameter or it will not work.

[syntax difference in query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXfyJ.png)

I am reasonably sure this is the cause of my issue, however I do not know how to make this fix in my backend code. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Do not pass a callback if you expect to get a promise returned.

Comment: `rowCount: 0` means that no user with the name `:Timmy` was found. You want to make your POST request to `http://localhost:5000/users/Timmy` - without the colon!